# How to access values printed to screen while waiting for ajax result?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending ajax request to a php file with jquery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            url: VIP_AJAX_URL + '/add',
            data: 'slug=' + slug,
            method: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function () {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Please wait..',
                    html: 'We are checking. <br/>This process may take some time.',
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    didOpen: () => {
                        Swal.showLoading()
                    }
                })
            },
            success: function (res) {
                if (res !== 'success') {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        html: res,
                    })
                    return;
                }

                console.log(res);
            }
        })
```

While this request is in progress, I am printing to the screen at intervals in the php file.

```
echo 'abc';
sleep(5);
echo 'def';
sleep(5);
echo 'ghi';
```

But after all the processes are finished, the ajax process is terminated. I want to reach the values ​​printed on the screen while the processes are in progress.

For example, I want to get the 'abc' value when the request is made, 'def' after 5 seconds, and 'ghi' after 10 seconds. How can I do it? I want to do it without using session, cookie or database.

Comment: AJAX is not the appropriate method for this, you need to use something like WebSockets.

Answer (score 1):

no. you can not

you can only do that on the front end

you can take the response intervally then add it to the html view with append() so it keeps growing

```js
function getLog() {                
fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/prabansal/115387/raw/0e5911c791c03f2ffb9708d98cac70dd2c1bf0ba/HelloWorld.txt").then(async e=>{
        let t = await e.text()
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += t+"<br/>"
    })
}
setInterval(getLog, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

i always use it when displaying progress in javascript, for example php artisan migrate process on laravel

Comment: He can also use websockets - they are probably much better and stable solution for that.